# Ask Ubuntu session at the Ubuntu Developer Summit

Tags: discussion, uds-n

On Friday will be a session where Mr Robert from SE will talk about Ask Ubuntu called **How to integrate with Ask Ubuntu** , you can connect and chat directly and your questions will be answered, and  visit the following links [here](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/) and [here](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-n/2010-10-29/)

It will be at 16:15 EDT. You can participate remotely using the [#ubuntu-uds-bonaire1](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-uds-bonaire1) IRC channel. You can listen to the live stream by downloading [this file](http://icecast.ubuntu.com:8000/bonaire1.ogg.m3u) and opening it with a media player.

GOOD ROCK!

Comment: **Time zone info** might be usefull: [Current Offset for **Ubuntu Developer Summit** ](http://worldtimeengine.com/dotime/orlando_fl_usa/): **UTC/GMT -4:00 Hours**