# What was discussed, and what was the outcome of the Ask Ubuntu UDS-N session?

Tags: discussion, uds-n

There was an [Ask Ubuntu session at UDS-N](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/610/ask-ubuntu-session-at-the-ubuntu-developer-summit) on Friday 29th October 2010.

What topics were discussed?

What decisions were made?

Comment: As I can see, for each session of UDS there's a written record which can be saved to the local via Gobby and they are usually available the end of the sessions, but for this session time was not enough at the end of the session to place it to place it there, I think. Jorge Castro might provide us with it.

Comment: Waiting for it.

Comment: I provided it and IRC log additionally. BTW, while writing this comment I realize that @Dor already provided a link. Appearently we were writing at the same time. I'm not deleting at the moment. We'll clear later.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This post aims to provide two documents related with the session.

**1 - The written short record of the session taken during the session**:

Publicly available source as of 30.10.2010 01:00 UTC via collaborative text editor [Gobby](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gobby-0.5), with server: document `ubuntutheproject/ubuntutheproject-community-n-ask-ubuntu` on server `gobby.ubuntu.com`.

```
Agenda
 * How to make site more accessible
   - screen readers will read it
   - possible issue with color compatibility
 * Localisation
   - number one priority for us (most users are international)
   - Would be nice to have a subdomain (eg nl.askubuntu.com)
     -- could then have a shared database of questions, but automatically tagged with language
     -- possibly making community wikis translatable (flag needed to indicate outdated translations)
     -- would make it possible for multilingual answerers to look at other pages
     -- currently we lack an askubuntu.com alternative for multiple languages (shapado can be used instead)
   - The software is running on proprietary software - we should see if open source technologies can be linked to that (e.g. gettext)
 * Replacing Launchpad answers (for Ubuntu project)
   - non-english bug reports session wants to use this for non-english bug reporters
     - questions can be converted to bugs and vice versa
   - would be nice to convert a launchpad bug to an askubuntu question
     - might be nice to be able to reconvert and automatically pull data back
       - existing launchpad bugs get converted to questions and back somewhat frequently
   - might be difficult to turn off answers in launchpad
     - redirecting to askubuntu would be different (eg with 15 day warning)
       - dealing with questions asked during transition period would also be a problem
 * Integrating ask into existing work team processes
   - encourage people on ask to link to official documentation (rather than just giving answer for instance)
     - would help boost search ranks of official documenation too
 * open source
   - we are following stackexchange here mostly
     - has hundreds of thousands of developers
 * how community can use database dumps (cc-licensed) 
   - in case stackexchange gets eaten by godzilla
   - "offline wikipedia CD"
 * Loco team integration
 * Default bookmark / adding ask link on stub page
   - bug filed in firefox to update default links LP: 602265
Work Items
 * [marco] 508 compliance research (site has to be this for US Gov $$$)
 * [jorge] bring up replacing answers in launchpad stakeholder process with Marjo (they have 6 month backlog or so)
 * [jorge] talk to online services: change start.ubuntu.com (in english) help link to "Ask a question" that links to stackexchange
 * [chris coulson] make a default bookmark for askubuntu and drop launchpad answers
```

**2- Log of the IRC chat parallel to the session**:

From [ubottu.com](http://ubottu.com/uds-logs/%23ubuntu-uds-bonaire1.log)

```
2010-10-29T20:08:54  <txwikinger> o/ Jorge
2010-10-29T20:09:34  <txwikinger> ok
2010-10-29T20:09:45  <badp> speaker: sooo ahead of you :P
2010-10-29T20:11:25  <txwikinger> great
2010-10-29T20:12:30  <txwikinger> Jorge: I announced the details in the askubuntu.com general chat
2010-10-29T20:14:01  <txwikinger> txwikinger is Ralph Janke
2010-10-29T20:14:18  <txwikinger> Hello Robert
2010-10-29T20:14:39  <txwikinger> rofl
2010-10-29T20:15:15  <marenostrum> marenostrum is Deniz. Launchpad: ~kdenizogut
2010-10-29T20:15:27  * nUboon2Age is Drew Johnson, involved in wiki documentation for ubuntu beginners
2010-10-29T20:15:40  <AlanBell> hello people who want to exchange their stack
2010-10-29T20:15:54  <marcoceppi> They don't call it a StackExchange for nothing!
2010-10-29T20:15:56  <dv3500ea> dv3500ea is David. Launchpad: ~david4dev
2010-10-29T20:16:12  <AlanBell> there is a bit of a concern from the Accessibility team about askubuntu.com and accessibility
2010-10-29T20:16:21  <AlanBell> as there is lots of ajax stuff going on
2010-10-29T20:16:43  <AlanBell> we believe they have at times broken accessibility
2010-10-29T20:16:47  <txwikinger> what is our document?
2010-10-29T20:16:50  <AlanBell> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68898/how-accessible-are-the-stack-exchange-sites-for-users-of-screen-reader-software
2010-10-29T20:17:05  <AlanBell> http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=blind+accessibility
2010-10-29T20:17:25  <badp> if you're fine with read-only access there are more accessible interfaces
2010-10-29T20:17:42  <badp> example: http://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu
2010-10-29T20:18:06  <AlanBell> not neccessarily a huge or unfixable problem but I would ask you to bear accessibility in mind, we want to bring all the ubuntu sites up to scratch in this regard
2010-10-29T20:18:31  <marcoceppi> AlanBell, As in 508 Compliant?
2010-10-29T20:18:41  <AlanBell> marcoceppi: well that would be nice
2010-10-29T20:18:54  <badp> AlanBell: that's not something the AskUbuntu team can do much about, you'll have to contact the StackExchange dev team at meta.stackexchange.com
2010-10-29T20:19:29  <txwikinger> Jorge: Are we using gobby or something else?
2010-10-29T20:19:36  <AlanBell> badp: I know, but if there are plans to move stuff from the wiki over to askubuntu.com then we don't want to introduce an accessibility regression
2010-10-29T20:19:38  <marcoceppi> From what I have seen, and know of 508 Compliancy - the style and engine for SE is pretty much there - though there are a few small things that would likely need to be changed. Primarily colors
2010-10-29T20:19:43  <marcoceppi> AlanBell, From what I have seen, and know of 508 Compliancy - the style and engine for SE is pretty much there - though there are a few small things that would likely need to be changed. Primarily colors
2010-10-29T20:19:50  <badp> you may be interested in WeMenu integration too
2010-10-29T20:19:52  <AlanBell> good stuff
2010-10-29T20:20:15  <txwikinger> speak up please
2010-10-29T20:20:20  <Morasique> i don't use the same nick on IRC as on SE; i feel like i'm in stealth mode
2010-10-29T20:20:22  <AlanBell> anyhow, I have to pop to the summit session, have fun with your stacks!
2010-10-29T20:20:50  <marcoceppi> Jorge: Sure
2010-10-29T20:21:10  <txwikinger> Jorge - we will have a similar law soon in Ontario
2010-10-29T20:22:58  <txwikinger> We might want to have multiple translations of the same question/asnwer?
2010-10-29T20:23:27  <badp> Honestly that sounds like a terrible idea.
2010-10-29T20:23:47  <Morasique> it's hard to keep them in sync, wikipedia has this problem
2010-10-29T20:24:48  <txwikinger> http://ubuntu.shapado.com
2010-10-29T20:26:02  <patcito> shapado.com runs on ubuntu by the way
2010-10-29T20:26:16  <badp> it's an open ghost town, yeah :)
2010-10-29T20:26:31  <txwikinger> shapado is a ruby on rails app
2010-10-29T20:26:38  <marcoceppi> It's based on the design of the "StackExchange 1.0" engine
2010-10-29T20:26:54  <patcito> badp: http://ask.debian.net is pretty active though and officially supported by debian.org
2010-10-29T20:27:00  <patcito> and it uses shapado
2010-10-29T20:27:14  <patcito> (I'm a shapado dev by the way)
2010-10-29T20:27:45  <badp> didn't know about that site :)
2010-10-29T20:28:03  <patcito> it's the official debian q&a site
2010-10-29T20:34:48  <badp> use the API and the monthly dumps
2010-10-29T20:35:55  <badp> http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help + http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/ + http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/
2010-10-29T20:36:46  <txwikinger> It's only the English questions anyway until we are multi-lingual
2010-10-29T20:38:55  <badp> I don't really think i18n can work. It's a matter of audience, rather than technical challenges.
2010-10-29T20:39:17  <badp> See StackExchange 1.0 (money) vs StackExchange 2.0 (audience)
2010-10-29T20:41:40  <badp> press the power button and pop in the oranger version between kubuntu and ubuntu in the cd tray
2010-10-29T20:42:00  <badp> http://chat.askubuntu.com/transcript/message/11770#11770
2010-10-29T20:43:49  <this_is_a_test> What is oranger, Ubuntu or Kubuntu?
2010-10-29T20:44:02  <txwikinger> Jorge: This is a matter of voting
2010-10-29T20:45:05  <txwikinger> 200 to retag
2010-10-29T20:45:14  <marcoceppi> http://askubuntu.com/privileges
2010-10-29T20:45:15  <txwikinger> 150 to create new tag
2010-10-29T20:45:37  <txwikinger> you can always ask a friendly moderator to help you :D
2010-10-29T20:45:41  <badp> tag wiki page requires being one of the top 20 answerers and having enough reputation
2010-10-29T20:46:18  <badp> +editing
2010-10-29T20:46:27  <Morasique> (1500, not 1000 like they said)
2010-10-29T20:48:03  <marcoceppi> Activity is edits, answers, responses
2010-10-29T20:48:19  <marcoceppi> for Hot it's like upvotes, page views, and above activity
2010-10-29T20:49:58  <Morasique> "1500 reputation is like a couple days of using the site" :)
2010-10-29T20:50:04  <patcito> stop coughing in the microphone
2010-10-29T20:50:45  <marcoceppi> One good answer can easily land you 250 reputation
2010-10-29T20:51:04  <Morasique> marcoceppi: not in a couple days, there's a limit
2010-10-29T20:51:14  <marcoceppi> 250 is the daily limit
2010-10-29T20:51:35  <Morasique> is it not 200 like the other sites? anyway, my point was a couple days would put you at ~500 rep, even maxing it out
2010-10-29T20:51:42  <txwikinger> 200 is the daily limit (however accepted answers can go over the limit)
2010-10-29T20:52:10  <marcoceppi> Ah, 250 was the most I got - txwikinger is right it's 200
2010-10-29T20:52:52  * txwikinger cheers on the security team
2010-10-29T20:53:01  <patcito> there are ways to get more than 200 rep per day http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day
2010-10-29T20:53:38  <Morasique> patcito: yeah, txwikinger said it, accepted answers
2010-10-29T20:53:48  <marcoceppi> So many points to cover, so little time
2010-10-29T20:54:47  <txwikinger> but we certainly encourage stackexchange to look into using and developing open source
2010-10-29T20:56:58  <patcito> stackoverflow have been giving database dumps for a few years and nothing special came out of it btw
2010-10-29T20:57:26  <marcoceppi> Just because no one uses it doesn't mean it won't be used sometime soon :P
2010-10-29T20:57:50  <Morasique> well, odata used it, but just to provide a way to search it, not in any particularly clever way
2010-10-29T20:57:58  <marcoceppi> There are a few questions like this
2010-10-29T20:57:59  <marcoceppi> http://askubuntu.com/questions/2872/what-are-the-biggest-barriers-to-walking-the-motu-developer-path
2010-10-29T21:00:35  <this_is_a_test> why did my stream randomly pause?
2010-10-29T21:00:51  <days_of_ruin> That happened to me too.
2010-10-29T21:01:23  <marcoceppi> mad rep for that
2010-10-29T21:01:56  <marcoceppi> Other people are upvoting
2010-10-29T21:02:01  <htorque> yeah :P
2010-10-29T21:02:33  <days_of_ruin> holy cow, it gets more upvotes every time I refresh
2010-10-29T21:02:49  <marcoceppi> mass effect
2010-10-29T21:06:31  <txwikinger> Jorge: In Quebec you will be sued
2010-10-29T21:07:39  <marenostrum> Is written report of the session available on Gooby? Name?
2010-10-29T21:08:02  <this_is_a_test> Hello
2010-10-29T21:08:08  <txwikinger> Thanks Jorge.. thanks Robert for coming
2010-10-29T21:08:23  <marenostrum> Thanks a lot dear friends.
2010-10-29T21:08:48  <dv3500ea> Thanks.
2010-10-29T21:09:16  <hhlp> thx
```

**Later edit :**

**3- [How to integrate with Ask Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UDSProceedings/N/UbuntuTheProject#How%20to%20integrate%20with%20Ask%20Ubuntu) subtitle on Ubuntu Wiki**:

> - [StackExchange](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StackExchange)
>     will look into ways to localise
>     [AskUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AskUbuntu),
>     so sites like 'nl.askubuntu.com' may
>     become reality;
> - Chris Coulson will look into replacing Launchpad Answers with
>     [AskUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AskUbuntu)
>     in the default Firefox bookmarks;
> - Marco will investigate 508 compliance for
>     [AskUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AskUbuntu);
> - [JorgeCastro](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JorgeCastro)
>     will discuss with Marjo ask for
>     replacing Launchpad Answers with a
>     redirection to
>     [AskUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AskUbuntu)
>     for Ubuntu, in the Launchpad
>     stakeholders meetings;
> - [JorgeCastro](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JorgeCastro)
>     will look into changing the 'Ubuntu
>     Help' link on the default Ubuntu start
>     page to link to
>     [AskUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AskUbuntu).

Comment: Erm... The last blockquote, the first link for the StackExchange wiki page is broken.