# Comes ask Ubuntu in different languages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any plans for localized Ask Ubuntu instances?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/533/are-there-any-plans-for-localized-ask-ubuntu-instances)

I am native speaking german. Would be great to have this site in my language.
What should I do?

Comment: Questions about this site itself belong on http://meta.askubuntu.com/

Comment: BTW askdebian comes with languages, but sadly no russian at all..

Answer (score 2):

The [results of the UDS session](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/631/what-was-discussed-and-what-was-the-outcome-of-the-ask-ubuntu-uds-n-session/634#634) will help answer your question. (Short story: yes, the SO team is aware of our needs for multi-language support)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a reputation for promoting diversity through its **Non-English support**. Due to it, people around the world can use Ubuntu in their native language or choosing one of the several different [languages](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/locallanguage). We also have the efforts of **LoCo Teams**, promoting and coordinating the community around the world.

Both (**Non-English support** and **LoCo Teams**) are reasons for Ask Ubuntu to support another idioms questions.

Comment: Great answer, but it's for a different Question.