# Accessibility and AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion

I know there was some consideration in the past about making sure Askubuntu was accessible (usable with screenreader software, e.g.).  For instance, the UDS-N session in October 2010 included talk about 508 compliance (documented in this post :  [What was discussed, and what was the outcome of the Ask Ubuntu UDS-N session?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/631/what-was-discussed-and-what-was-the-outcome-of-the-ask-ubuntu-uds-n-session) ).

Has there been any more work done on 508 compliance or accessibility?
What further actions can we take to make sure AskUbuntu is an accessible site?

Here are some related meta.stackoverflow posts:

[Accessibility with Screen Reading Software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68898/how-accessible-are-the-stack-exchange-sites-for-users-of-screen-reader-software)

[Bringing Up Accessibility Issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions5207/stackoverflow-accessibility-with-screen-reading-software)

[Encouraging People to Use Alt-Text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text)

Answer (score 4):

Back during the UDS-N I ran several compliancy check tools that were available via the work I was doing on location at [Danya International](http://danya.com) (employed there at the time). Ask Ubuntu passed all the tests with just several warnings about alt and title tags missing. I haven't run the tool against the site in a few months, and since my contract work there is done I no longer have access to these tools.

I'll see if I can have the reports generated again for the site and post the results here.

Answer (score 3):

One area where we can improve the site in this regard is in helpful and consistent use of Alt tags.  For some guidelines on how to do this, see [How to Use Alt-Text](http://www.abilitynet.org.uk/webarticle20) .