# link up unanswered questions from a launchpad mailing list to askubuntu?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

Is there a way to hook up unanswered questions from a launchpad mailing list to askubuntu?
I thought the poor man's solution would be to just copy+paste the mailing list question to askubuntu and reply to the mailing list with the askubuntu URL, but maybe there is something better out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LP Answers currently doesn't have a way to connect to an external source (such as AU) to a project.

We've discussed this at a UDS and currently it's on a "wow this would be great to have" column, but it wouldn't be useful if we were trying to do this by hand as it would be confusing to people unless we did it right.

- [What was discussed, and what was the outcome of the Ask Ubuntu UDS-N session?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/631/what-was-discussed-and-what-was-the-outcome-of-the-ask-ubuntu-uds-n-session)

Comment: it would be really cool to have some method to give reputation to answered launchpad questions, even if both are kept separate